# How to remove all activity in flow from stack, when calling some new activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a problem in my android app, it having the log out functionality in setting screen.
When we Logout it opens the login screen. But when i press back button then it show the setting screen page, which is not required (as it takes me to inside the app without login). I am using the following code but it is not working. Because at the time of logout LoginActiviy is not exist.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(HomeSetting.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Please suggest me some solution, that LoginActivity get call as a new Activity, and all activity in history will get destroyed.

Comment: Why dont you call finish() on while calling second screen.

Comment: There are so many screens in flow, so i can't set finish() to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `noHistory` property of Activity in manifest file as `true`.So it will be removed from Activity satck,when it goes to background.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you should set flags as follows:

```
     Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext() , LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: have you tried giving getApplicationContext() in place of HomeSetting.this. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, It will not work as LoginActivity gets call as a new Activity, not from the Activity stack, I am looking for a solution for this scenario, in which we able to clear all activity history from stack, when launching a new Intent.